# Declaring a const variable as reference

Tags: c++, reference, declaration

At some places I have seen variables declared like this

```
const int &var1;
extern int & var2;
```

These variables are defined somewhere else. I always thought that when you declare a reference to a variable you bind the reference to that variable at the same place. I am missing something here. Also I have not seen references declared as above when there is no qualifier (e.g. const or extern).

Comment: Are these global variables, local variables (in a function) or class member variables? It's common to have class member variables as references, and you initialize them in a constructor initializer list.

Comment: These are class member variables. Any particular advantage with this style? And is it possible to declare all class member variables like this or there are any limitations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual declaration of a variable, let it be a reference or a pointer or a normal variable, has nothing to do with the type of a variable.

Even if in your examples you have references to variables this means nothing related to where they are initialized. Having a reference is useful because you assign it from another variable and you can actually use them as a pointer without caring about dereferincing it but nothing more, it is a variable like any other.

Comment: Except you cannot default initialize the reference or assign to it. So there are some restrictions as to where they are initialized if they are data members.

Comment: "The actual declaration of a variable, let it be a reference or a pointer or a normal variable, has nothing to do with the type of a variable." - other than the fact that the declaration specifies the type.

Comment: Of course a reference must be initialized, since it's a reference. What I meant is that the restriction of a reference initialization has nothing to do with the scope of the declaration. A reference must be initialized in a block of code that is actually executed in a context related tomthe declaration, eg a constructor.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: what I meant is that a declaration is just a declaration, nothing special applies related to where a declaration of a reference variable is done if it initialized in a context that is executed afterwards.

Answer (score 6):

```
const int &var1;
```

this is illegal if not part of a `class` or a `struct`. If it is, it must be initialized in the constructor **initializer list**.

The reason it's legal is because the variable doesn't exist until an object of that class is created. So there's no unbound reference, as there is no reference to speak of.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main()
{
    const int &var1;   
}
```

> prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>
> prog.cpp:4: error: ‘var1’ declared as reference but not initialized
>
> prog.cpp:6: error: assignment of read-only reference ‘var1’

***EDIT***: As others have said it can be part of `class` and be initialized in a constructor